# Eclipse install previous version of plug-in

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I developed an Eclipse plug-in and installed it in Eclipse. After making some modifications in the plug-in source, I re-released that plugin in an Update Site. I tried to get the plug-in through "new software install menu" and re-install the plug-in in Eclipse, but the installed version of the plug-in is not the current version; it is the previous one. How can I adapt the current plug-in in Eclipse mantaining the plug-in version?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the version number of your feature before releasing it to the update site? Eclipse checks the version number, and only installs the new version if its version number is newer than the one already installed.